# How to save a Visual Studio Code ThunderClient request as a file?

Tags: visual-studio, vscode-extensions, web-api-testing, thunderclient

What I am trying to accomplish is to save a visual studio thunder client request as a file. I have gone to the settings and placed a check in the checkmark `Thunder-client: Save Request On Send`. Then when on the Thunder Client extension screen I am able to save the request however I am not able to save it to a file. In the docs it states the default folder is `thunder-tests`.

How are we able to save a thunder client request to file?

Answer (score 5):

Hi To save requests to git project, please enable the vscode setting ***Save To Workspace***

Then it will create ***thunder-tests*** folder in your current workspace and also save requests in that folder.

for more details visit here
https://github.com/rangav/thunder-client-support#git-sync

Comment: Thank you for the info. I have enabled the setting `Save to Workspace`; however I am unclear how the request are saved in that folder (there is no save button or option). That folder didn't get created so I manually created it. But I am not able to understand how to save the request as a file. In that docs it's not clear how to save it to the file nor any examples online that I can see.

Comment: Open your project in vscode first, and start creating requests in thunder client, it will create necessary files and folder.

Comment: FYI - git sync is a paid feature, so you'll need to subscribe